# Maven profile plugins

Tags: maven, plugins, pom.xml, profile

I have a maven application with many profiles defined in pom.xml. I'd like to run webstart-maven-plugin in (almost) each profile. The obvious solution is to copy-paste the plugin definition into the all profile section in pom.xml. But this plugin has many parameters and it's not easy to maintain changes...

Is there a possibility to define the plugin parameters once and reference/include/override this parametrized one in required profiles?

Comment: Why do you have many profiles? Could it be that other Maven mechanism let you achieve your goals easier/better?

Comment: It's a multi project application. There is a core.jar with common functions, but if a customer ask extra functionality it will be implemented in an "extra" jar. So all profile specifies the dependency for the "extra_userx.jar". And since it's a java webstart application I use webstart-maven-plugin to create jnlp, sign jars, etc.

Comment: One more thing: Because of java webstart application the signed jar must contain the jnlp or jnlp template, which contains the list of libraries. The webstart-maven-plugin helps in it too.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it by defining a parent pom. In parent pom `<packaging>pom</packaging>` specified and the parametrized webstart-maven-plugin placed in it. The child pom must reference to parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.bgy.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>./parent.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

In profiles of the child pom where plugin execution not necessary there is:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>                
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <phase>none</phase>
         </execution>
     </executions>
 </plugin>
```

and in profiles where execution necessary:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>                
</plugin>
```

(you can omit this)